# Counting triplets from three arrays satisfying the equation x^2 = yz

Tags: data-structures, number-theory, counting, mathematical-programming

Let's say I have three arrays of positive integers `X`, `Y` and `Z`. You can assume that each of the arrays have atmost $N$ elements. All the arrays contain unique elements.

You're allowed to form a triplet of integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are elements from arrays `X`, `Y` and `Z` respectively.

I want to count the number of such triplets satisfying the equation $x^2 = yz$. I can only think of an $O(N^2)$ solution using simple hashing. I was wondering if there exists a better solution with a time complexity of $O(N \lg N)$ at least, if not $O(N)$.

Comment: How large are the integers?  Can you share more about the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the original source of the problem, if you saw it somewhere?

Comment: "Obviously", a non-concurrent $O(N\lg N)$ time solution will be in $O(N\lg N)$ space.

Comment: Worst case will be difficult. For random largish numbers, you could sort all arrays by largest prime factor, and if a number in Y has a prime factor p, then there must be a number in Z with a factor p, p^3 etc. and a corresponding number in X - this may allow you to remove lots of numbers, and reduce the number of cases a lot.

Comment: @D.W. I was trying to solve this problem after inspiring from the Two-sum Problem. It can be solved in $O(N)$. I was wondering if this problem (for a 3-variable equation) can be solved in $O(N \lg N)$, if not as good as $O(N)$. It's not a textbook problem so it doesn't really have any value limits as such. Let's say there's no restriction on the amount of memory that you can use, for simplicity.

Comment: @greybeard No, I'm looking for a serial algorithm.

Comment: If you do not limit the sizes of the integers, then 3sum reduces to this problem.

Comment: Does there exist an $O(N)$ solution for the Three-Sum Problem? I didn't get one

Comment: The 3SUM problem is [conjectured to have no algorithm that runs much faster than $O(n^2)$ time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).  The reduction is: set $X=\{2^{2a} : a \in A\}$, $Y=\{2^b : b \in B\}$, $Z=\{2^c : c \in C\}$; then the 3SUM problem with sets $A,B,C$ is equivalent to your problem with sets $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: If the integers were random and small, you could factor them, representing $x$ by the vector $e=(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ where $x=p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ and $p_1,\dots,p_k$ is the list of small primes; then search for $y,z$ whose vectors $f,g$ satisfy $f \equiv g \pmod 2$ (this can be done in $O(n)$ time using a hashtable); for each such pair, such whether $yz \in X$.  I don't know whether this would be competitive with other approaches, but it might be better for some specific distributions on $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: I take non-concurrent, sequential and "serial" to mean the same thing. The trivial observation $O(f(N)) time \subset O(f(N)) space$ might have been helpful to preclude some ideas for preprocessing.

Comment: @D.W. can you illustrate this method using an example?

Comment: We only need to find factors up to y^(1/3): If y has no factors up to y^(1/3) and z has no factors up to z^(1/3), then both are either prime or factor of two primes, and their product can only be a square if y = z (if we exclude squares in the first place; if y or z is sqare then yz is square  iff both are square. If there are many squares then we take the square roots and check if yz is in X). That should make life easier for say 15-18 digit numbers.

Comment: @UrbanCentral I thought about a very similar approach, just calculate a bit vector for each y, z with bit i set if y has a prime factor of the i-th prime raised to an odd power. For yz to be a square, y and z must have equal bit vectors. This is helpful as long as many integers have random small factors. Even with huge numbers it may very much reduce the search space.